# Ruby on Rails - Opening a file using Spreadsheet RubyGem

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, rubygems, spreadsheet

I think I'm probably missing something quite simple, as I am new to this gem (and Ruby/Rails in general), but here we go...

I just installed the Spreadsheet gem from RubyGems and used Bundler to install it. Following that, I restarted my local server.

I want to create my database from an Excel file I have, but am struggling to open the file. The code I have is:

```
require 'spreadsheet'
Spreadsheet.client_encoding = 'UTF-8'

book = Spreadsheet.open('C:\Users\Lev Berlin\Documents\Personal\Projects
  \FactsRus\Nutritional Analysis Models\Data for Rails model import.xls')
sheet1 = book.worksheet('Sheet1')
```

And the error I get after running >rails runner script/load_excel_file.rb (which has the code above) is:

Permission denied - C:\Users...import.xls (Errno::EACCES)

Like I said - I'm probably missing something very simple, but any pointers would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problem was that the file I was trying to read from was open! N00b mistake, but I eventually figured it out.

Thanks all for looking.

Comment: This is the second time I am running into this problem and read your answer. :-) Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

use parseexcel in gem file instead of spreadsheet.

```
gem 'parseexcel'
```

write below code in db/seed.rb file place your excel file in project/db/data folder

```
def seed_cities
  workbook = Spreadsheet::ParseExcel.parse("#{Dir.getwd}/db/data/cities.xls")

  workbook.worksheet(0).each(1) { |row|
    next if row == nil;
    col = row.at(0);
    next if col == nil;
    id = col.to_s('latin1').strip;
    next if id == "";

    country_id = row.at(1).to_s('latin1').strip;
    state_id = row.at(2).to_s('latin1').strip;
    name = row.at(3).to_s('latin1').strip;
    code = row.at(4).to_s('latin1').strip;

    city = City.new(:country_id => country_id, :state_id => state_id, :name => name, :code => code)

    unless city.save
      city.errors.each { |e| puts "Database Error: ", e }
    end
  }

end

seed_cities()
```

this is my cities.xls excel file

```
id  country_id  state_id    name               code 
1   7            77          Lahore            LHR  
2   7            77          Islamabad         ISB
```

Comment: Does Spreadsheet always need an additional gem to be able to read in data from Excel or is this just the way you are pulling Excel data?

Comment: actually parseexcel do all the magic stuff. Don't need to open close the excel file. This is working code. If you got permissions error just right click on project folder and give permission to 'Everyone' have full control.

Comment: It looks like I have 'Full Control' via the permissions, still pretty confused what the problem is.

Comment: gotcha...maybe it's because I'm running in a Windows environment. I'll try out parse